Spring Data JDBC Repository Bean Creation Error
I am using Spring Data Jdbc and have activated it in the main application as follows
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJdbcRepositories
@EnableJdbcAuditing
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}

I have created an Artist repository as follows
@Repository
public interface ArtistRepository extends CrudRepository<Artist, UUID> {

    Artist findByVerificationPhase(VerificationPhase verificationPhase);
}

and have injected it to the service layer using lombok RequiredArgsConstructor as follows
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ArtistService {

    private final ArtistRepository artistRepository;
}

However, when I run the code it complains about creating a bean of type artistReposiroty and artistService and getting the following log
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artistController' defined in file [/Users/bob/personal/stest/build/classes/java/main/com/example/test/app/service/artist/controller/ArtistController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'artistService' defined in file [/Users/bob/personal/test/build/classes/java/main/com/example/test/app/service/artist/service/ArtistService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'artistRepository' defined in com.example.test.app.service.artist.repository.ArtistRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on TestApplication: A constructor parameter name must not be null to be used with Spring Data JDBC; Offending parameter: org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@ab8c9847
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at com.example.test.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:14) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artistService' defined in file [/Users/bob/personal/test/build/classes/java/main/com/example/test/app/service/artist/service/ArtistService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'artistRepository' defined in com.example.test.app.service.artist.repository.ArtistRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on TestApplication: A constructor parameter name must not be null to be used with Spring Data JDBC; Offending parameter: org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@ab8c9847
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'artistRepository' defined in com.example.test.app.service.artist.repository.ArtistRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on TestApplication: A constructor parameter name must not be null to be used with Spring Data JDBC; Offending parameter: org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@ab8c9847
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A constructor parameter name must not be null to be used with Spring Data JDBC; Offending parameter: org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@ab8c9847
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.mapping.JdbcMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(JdbcMappingContext.java:73) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.mapping.JdbcMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(JdbcMappingContext.java:40) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:407) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:282) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:282) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:198) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 44 common frames omitted


Any idea why jdbc is unable to create a bean?

Are you providing correct data base properties ??please share your properties or yaml file

Share your Artist class. Also spring will not be able to inject ArtistRepository into your service using @RequiredArgsConstructor

This is a variant of the problem described here: Is it possible to get rid of @Param Annotation in Spring Data JPA Repository
Spring Data needs parameter names in (at least) two situations:

To match method arguments to named bind parameters in queries
Match constructor parameters to properties

The java compiler by default drops the name information of parameters but can be instructed to keep it with the -parameters flag.
In maven you configure that using
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

The question referenced above links to additional information.
Most people don't explicitly need this flag because Spring Boot sets it for them.

Turns out  the check was to strict and we removed it just now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1762
